# Why does my recyclerviewer only display entries when I switch to landscape (rotate my phone)?

Tags: java, android-studio

I realized after having run my application on a phone instead of an emulator, that things are not working out properly.

On the emulator the recyclerviewer displays entries as expected. When I switched over to phone, at first, no entries were showing. But when I switch to landscape view (rotate phone 90 degrees) they become visible, and remain so even when I rotate back.

I'm working on a project with many others, so it is hard for me to know where to look, or what code to post.

To make my question clear:

What could trigger this behaviour?

**Adapter**

```
public class LagerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LagerAdapter.LagerViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> myLagerDataset;

    public static class LagerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView lagerTextView;
        public LagerViewHolder(View lagerView) {
            super(lagerView);
            lagerTextView = (TextView) lagerView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_lager_title);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public LagerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent , int viewType) {
        View lagerView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_lager_rv, parent, false);

        LagerViewHolder lViewHolder = new LagerViewHolder(lagerView);
        return lViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(LagerViewHolder lagerholder, int position) {
        lagerholder.lagerTextView.setText(myLagerDataset.get(position));
    }


    public LagerAdapter(ArrayList<String> lagerDataset) {
        myLagerDataset = lagerDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myLagerDataset.size();
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class LagerActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private RecyclerView rv;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter lAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private  ArrayList<String> strings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lager);

        // 1. get a reference to recyclerView
        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.lager_recycler_view);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        strings = new ArrayList<>();

        Call<List<Article>> call = Utils.getApi().getArticles();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Article>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<List<Article>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                int statusCode = response.code();
                Log.i(MainActivity.class.getName(), "Status: " + statusCode);

                List<Article> articles = response.body();

                if (articles != null) {
                    for (Article p : articles) {
                        strings.add(p.toString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    strings.add("Inga varor hittades ...");
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.i(MainActivity.class.getName(), "Failed to fetch data: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });

        lAdapter = new LagerAdapter(strings);

        rv.setAdapter(lAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_lager, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        // lagerhanterings alternativ
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HandleLagerActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**XML 1**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lager_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**XML 2**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.proxymeister.antonsskafferi.LagerActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_lager_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the source code for the activity and the adapter, as well as the activity's layout xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the code that creates the recyclerviewer in a worker thread, which speeds up the time it takes for it to set up. Problem is that the main thread is slow, so when you enter the view nothing shows up (but something is there, when you rotate you see that).

EDIT: the main thread is not inherently slow, just bad design from our part.